# HTML Agility Pack Parsing div

Tags: c#, parsing, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to parse HTML, I need to get "text" from this part:

```
<div class="_gdf kno-fb-ctx">
    <span data-ved="0ahUKEwjIr9brjO7UAhUnYZoKHda-ALgQ2koIogEoAjAT"> text</span>
</div>
```

Here's my C# code:

```
var message = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='_gdf kno-fb-ctx']").InnerText;
Console.WriteLine(message);
```

What I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are not selecting the actual 'Span' node to read the InnertTex. You have selected div and trying to read InnertTex, which won't give you desired result "Text". Instead you can do like below:

```
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml("<div class='_gdf kno-fb-ctx'><span data-ved = '0ahUKEwjIr9brjO7UAhUnYZoKHda-ALgQ2koIogEoAjAT'> text </span ></div >");
        var text = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class=\"_gdf kno-fb-ctx\"]//span").InnerText;
```

Comment: Hmm but then I can't use .InnerText 

"Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1061 'HtmlNodeCollection' does not contain a definition for 'InnerText' and no extension method 'InnerText' accepting a first argument of type 'HtmlNodeCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?"

Comment: Sorry for that, can you try SelectSingleNode instead of SelectNodes

Comment: Here and here is the same problem

Comment: Edited my code in above answer and which is working fine for me. I am able to execute and see the output

Comment: Did you try my updated code , from the answer above?